# How to force element state using cypress

Tags: cypress

i have a link which gets a text-decoration:underline when hovering. But i can´t reproduce it using cypress.

I´ve tried ex. `cy.get('a').trigger('mouseover')` but nothing happens.
Is there a way to force the element to have :hover state?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does not support hovering. But in a previous question this workaround has been suggested:

```js
it('hovering over button', () => {
  cy.visit("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
  cy.get('.mouse-hover-content').should('be.hidden').invoke('show');
})
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn´t work. cy.get('a').invoke('show').should('have.css', 'text-decoration', 'underline');

Comment: in that case there isn't a workaround available. You simple cannot test the hover functionality

Comment: Ahhh why? I can force :hover using chrome browser inspecting tool and it works when i hover manually

Comment: More information to that (and updates when it will come) can be found in this issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/10